# Подскажите как исправить не точность при раскрытие панели

Tags: jquery, css

Есть раскрывающаяся панель с левой стороны.

Если уменьшить её ширину, то при маленькой ширине (в локальной версии  `568` пикселей, в [**codepen**](https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/xzOyeX) - `375` пикселей), желтая панель с **id** `slider-arrow` исчезает.
 Почему так происходит?

И есть ли, какая-то альтернатива моему коду для уменьшения ширины экрана?
Я использовал `window resize`, там еще  было больше багов...

Подскажите пожалуйста почему так происходит и как исправить.

```js
if(window.matchMedia("(max-width:568px)").matches) {
    
    $('.slider-arrow').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('show')){
     $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          left: "+=200"
    }, 700, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
          $( ".panel .summer-buble" ).animate({
            left: "-=200"
            }, 1700, function() {
              // Animation complete.
            });
    $(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
        }
        else {    
     $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          left: "-=200"
    }, 700, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
          $( ".panel .summer-buble" ).animate({
            left: "+=200"
            }, 500, function() {
              // Animation complete.
            });
    $(this).removeClass('hide').addClass('show');    
        }
    });

}   else if(window.matchMedia("(max-width:8000px)").matches) {
    
    $('.slider-arrow').click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass('show')){
     $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          left: "+=300"
    }, 700, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
          $( ".panel .summer-buble" ).animate({
            left: "-=307"
            }, 1700, function() {
              // Animation complete.
            });
    $(this).removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
        }
        else {    
     $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          left: "-=300"
    }, 700, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
          $( ".panel .summer-buble" ).animate({
            left: "+=307"
            }, 500, function() {
              // Animation complete.
            });
    $(this).removeClass('hide').addClass('show');    
        }
    });

}
```

```css
.event-window {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5vh;
}

.panel {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  height: 280px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  left: -300px;
  border: 1px solid #FECC00;
}
.panel .summer-buble {
  position: absolute;
  left: 310px;
  bottom: -36px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .panel .summer-buble {
    left: 300px;
  }
}

.slider-arrow {
  height: 272px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  float: left;
  background: #FECC00;
  font: 400 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  left: -302px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .slider-arrow {
    width: 30px;
  }
}
.slider-arrow span {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#image {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  #image {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

.event-container {
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.event-container .event-block {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 25%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.event-container .event-block .event-img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-top: 5px;
}
.event-container .event-block .event-info {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  height: 90%;
}
.event-container .event-block .event-info .event-date {
  color: #DF8D95;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}
.event-container .event-block .event-info .event-preview {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 130%;
}
.event-container .more {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 0 15px 5px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event-window">
  <div class="panel">
    <img class="summer-buble" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwwTz.png">  
    <div class="event-container">
      <div class="event-block">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/60ZUY-jC46w/hqdefault.jpg" class="event-img">
        <div class="event-info">
          <span class="event-date">24.05.2018</span>
          <p class="event-preview">8 занятий на 25-26-27-28 мая</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="event-block">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/60ZUY-jC46w/hqdefault.jpg" class="event-img">
        <div class="event-info">
          <span class="event-date">24.05.2018</span>
          <p class="event-preview">ВИДЕО:Dubai AFISHA & YOGA SHANI - ДЫХАНИЯ ОГНЯ</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="event-block">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/60ZUY-jC46w/hqdefault.jpg" class="event-img">
        <div class="event-info">
          <span class="event-date">24.05.2018</span>
          <p class="event-preview">май:10 новых мест в DUBAI</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="more">more</a>
    </div> 
  </div>


  <div href="javascript:void(0);" id="slider-arrow" class="slider-arrow show">
    <span>#SUMMER</span>
    <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jyAsco/close.png" id="image">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: вы так и не научились медиа запросы писать в css !

Comment: @МаксимЛенский вы также написали между прочим :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде бы так плавнее и проще

```js
$("#slider-arrow").on("click", function() {
  $(".panel").toggleClass("show");
});

$(".slider-arrow").on("click", function() {
  $(".summer-buble").toggleClass("anim");
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.panel {
  width: 300px;
  height: 280px;
  background: #fff;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #FECC00;
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
  transition: all .4s linear;
}

.panel .summer-buble {
  position: absolute;
  left: 310px;
  bottom: -36px;
  transition: .6s;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .panel .summer-buble {
    left: 300px;
  }
}

.slider-arrow {
  height: 272px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 50px;
  background: #FECC00;
  font: 400 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  .slider-arrow {
    width: 30px;
  }
}

.slider-arrow span {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 22px;
}

#image {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 568px) {
  #image {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
}

.event-container {
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.event-container .event-block {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.event-container .event-block .event-img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.event-container .event-block .event-info {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 11px;
  padding: 5px 20px;
  height: 90%;
}

.event-container .event-block .event-info .event-date {
  color: #DF8D95;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  display: block;
}

.event-container .event-block .event-info .event-preview {
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  line-height: 130%;
}

.event-container .more {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding: 0 15px 5px 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.show {
  transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.anim {
  transform: translate(-300px, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="event-window">
  <div class="panel">
    <img class="summer-buble" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwwTz.png">
    <div class="event-container">
      <div class="event-block">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/60ZUY-jC46w/hqdefault.jpg" class="event-img">
        <div class="event-info">
          <span class="event-date">24.05.2018</span>
          <p class="event-preview">8 занятий на 25-26-27-28 мая</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="event-block">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/60ZUY-jC46w/hqdefault.jpg" class="event-img">
        <div class="event-info">
          <span class="event-date">24.05.2018</span>
          <p class="event-preview">ВИДЕО:Dubai AFISHA & YOGA SHANI - ДЫХАНИЯ ОГНЯ</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="event-block">
        <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/60ZUY-jC46w/hqdefault.jpg" class="event-img">
        <div class="event-info">
          <span class="event-date">24.05.2018</span>
          <p class="event-preview">май:10 новых мест в DUBAI</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="more">more</a>
    </div>
    <div href="javascript:void(0);" id="slider-arrow" class="slider-arrow show">
      <span>#SUMMER</span>
      <img src="https://image.ibb.co/jyAsco/close.png" id="image">
    </div>

  </div>




</div>
```